# Popup and fade message based on URL query string - CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [referral form on this page](https://idio.ai/thank-you-webinar-testing-ground/) which I want people to use multiple times.

Upon submitting the form it reloads the page with the query string `?referralsent=true` in order to be able to refer more people through the form.

However I'd want to show a confirmation to people that the invitation has been sent.

For this I thought it would be best if I temporarily display a popup message for a second or 2 after the reload - **"Invitation sent"**. This would then fade out.

I have no clue though how I would go about doing this. Do you have any examples maybe or on pointers on making this happen?

Comment: I'd like to see your code with the submit logic. I'd add a timeout function in there and after that expires, you can reload the page.

Comment: the code is on this page: https://idio.ai/thank-you-webinar-testing-ground/.
But if I understand correctly you'd display the message before and not when it reloaded, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'd delay the call to refresh. Also please share the code snippet that directly calls the refresh, not the entire page. It'll help us to solve your particular issue easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Timeout with Javascript:

Your HTML:

```
<div class="message hide" id="messageUser">
   <!-- Information User -->
</div>
```

Your CSS :

```
.message {
  display : block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding 20px;
}

.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

Your JS :

```
setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('messageUser').classList.remove('hide');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: this might be a start. But how would you only show this when the query string "?referralsent=true" exists in the URL?